# How to resolve NPM packages from different organization(Azure Devops)

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops, .npmrc

We have an NPM package say 'design' in say organization1, I have a pipeline which is part of the same organization that is able to resolve the package with just npmrc file. I wanted to access the packages 'design' from organization2, I am not able to read/resolve the package. pipeline throws 401.

1. I tried setting up Service connection in Azure devops and try to use - same response
2. tried with PAT directly on the npmrc file - same response
3. From this [blog](https://www.koskila.net/how-to-authenticate-against-npm-registries-in-azure-devops/), we have to set up all the properties, I tried - same response.

Is there I have to do something else to resolve the packages in external organization ?

latest .npmrc

```
@<reg>:registry=https://<reg>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/<feed>/npm/registry/
//https://<reg>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/<feed>/npm/registry/:_password=#{npm_PAT}#
//https://<reg>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/<feed>/npm/registry/:username="notrequired"
//https://<reg>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/<feed>/npm/registry/:email="not@required.ever"
//https://<reg>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/<feed>/npm/registry/:always-auth = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the packages in external organization, you can add the following content to .npmrc file:

**Project feed:**

```
; begin auth token
//orgname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/projectname/_packaging/456/npm/registry/:username=AzureTest23
//orgname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/projectname/_packaging/456/npm/registry/:_password=[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]
//orgname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/projectname/_packaging/456/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
//orgname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/projectname/_packaging/456/npm/:username=AzureTest23
//orgname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/projectname/_packaging/456/npm/:_password=[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]
//azuretest23.pkgs.visualstudio.com/projectname/_packaging/456/npm/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
; end auth token
```

**Organization Feed:**

```
; begin auth token
//orgname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/234/npm/registry/:username=AzureTest23
//orgname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/234/npm/registry/:_password=[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]
//orgname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/234/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
//orgname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/234/npm/:username=AzureTest23
//orgname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/234/npm/:_password=[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]
//orgname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/234/npm/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
; end auth token
```

Then you need to create a PAT with the **Packaging Read and Write**  permission of the organization1.

[image]

**Note:** You need to convert the PAT to **base64** type and replace the token value in .npmrc file.

To get the detailed settings, you can navigate to **Azure Feed -> Connect to feed -> NPM -> Other** and  check the .npmrc file settings.

[image]

**Update:**

To convert the PAT to base64 type, we can follow this doc: [Credentials setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=linux%2Cclassic#credentials-setup)

Comment: I want to add, I tried with powershell command to convert to base 64, it was failing in the pipeline. then I follow the one in documentation, it works https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=linux%2Cclassic#credentials-setup

Comment: Good point! I have updated my answer to include this point.